# Regex search won't accept parameter

Tags: c++, regex

Can someone kindly explain why in the code below there is one line that generates an error ?
For comparison, the next line compiles correctly.
For some reasons, the casting to std::string is not the same as suppling a std:: string type variable.
I am using Visual Studio 2019, C++, console application with default options.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex e;
    std::smatch sm;
    std::string str("abc");
    std::regex_search(std::string("abc"), sm, e);  // Doesn't compile
    std::regex_search(str, sm, e);  // Compiles correctly
}
```

Here's the error given by the pre-compiler
Sorry for the italian...

Gravità Codice  Descrizione Progetto    File    Riga    Stato eliminazione
Errore (attivo) E1776   impossibile fare riferimento a funzione "std::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem, _StTraits, _StAlloc> &&, std::match_results::const_iterator, _Alloc> &, const std::basic_regex<_Elem, _RxTraits> &, std::regex_constants::match_flag_type = std::regex_constants::match_default) [con _StTraits=std::char_traits, _StAlloc=std::allocator, _Alloc=std::allocator, std::_String_iter_types>>>>>, _Elem=char, _RxTraits=std::regex_traits]" (dichiarato alla riga 2300 di "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\regex"). È una funzione eliminata ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\munarid\source\repos\Unit-Test-Generation_Support\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp  9

Comment: You should include the compiler's error message in your question :)

Comment: If you visited this [web](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) , you would see `= delete` at the overload you want to call. So it is not surprising it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

That overload was deleted in C++ 2014.

The `smatch` result is a string iterator, and an iterator into the temporary argument object would be invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Ok, fine. 
I apologize for my limited knowledge of C++. 
My doubts remain, however...
why the std::string variable is ok and the casting is not ok ?

Comment: Fine. I start to see the light... 
looking here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search
at point 7) -----
7) The overload 3 is prohibited from accepting temporary strings, otherwise this function populates match_results m with string iterators that become invalid immediately.---- So the problem is the temporary variable. The casting produces a temporary variable, instead the "named" variable is not temporary. 
OK, thank to all for the support.